# Как передать возвращаемое функцией значение в условие чтобы что-то с ним сделать дальше?

Tags: javascript

При этом ещё, более не вызывая ту функцию из которой было передано значение.

Например:

```js
var round1 = $this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.dataset.step;

showsFollowingQuestions = function() {
  nextQuestion.call($this);
  $this.classList.add('correct');
  $this.parentNode.classList.add(delayHideAccordion);
  $this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.nextElementSibling.children[1].children[0].classList.add(delayShowAccordion)
  hideAnswerText.call($this);
  return;
};

if (round1 === 'game') {
  if ($trueQuestions || $trueQuestionsRound) {
    showsFollowingQuestions();
  } else {
    //здесь надо проверить что вернулось из функции "showsFollowingQuestions" 
    //грубо говоря если вернулось true тогда то что написано ниже не делать
    $this.classList.add('incorrect');
    hideAnswerText.call($this);
  }
}
```

Comment: Из функции "showsFollowingQuestions" ничего не вернулось. Чтобы из нее что-то вернулось, напишите "что-то" в `return что-то;`.

Comment: Ну, вероятно, возвращать из функции `true`/`false`, присвоить это переменной, и потом проверять ее(переменную) на истинность/ложность, нет?